# Codeigniter: Generate id on dynamic textbox/textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a problem generating ID's on my dynamic textareas.

Here is my model:

```
public function select_fields3($tablename3){
     $this->load->library('table');
     $fields = $this->db->field_data($tablename3['table1']);
     return $fields;
 }
```

Here is my controller:

```
 public function add_all_inventory(){
    $this->data['title'] = "Add New Inventory";
    $this->load->vars($this->data);
    $table_naming_1 = $_POST['table1'];
    $this->load->view('homeview');

    $select_inv['inventorytype'] = $this->inventory_model->select_tables();
    $this->load->view('inventoryview', $select_inv);

    $select_fields['add_all'] = $this->inventory_model->select_fields3($this->input->post());

    $values_array1 = array('add_all_1' => $select_fields['add_all'],
                           'tablename1' => $table_naming_1);

    $this->load->view('add_all_inventory', $values_array1);

    $this->load->view('footer_view');
}
```

No need to focus on $select_inv, it's just a reference so I can get the fields of the table loaded. And here is my view:

```
<div class="row">
<fieldset>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="frm_add_all_inventory" name="frm_add_all_inventory">
    <legend>Add New <input style="border: none; background-color: transparent;" type="text" name="txt_table" id="txt_table" value="<?php echo $tablename1; ?>" readonly/></legend>
            <table style="">
                <?php foreach($add_all_1 as $row) { ?>
                <tr style="">
                    <td style=" height: 50px; width: 100px;font-size: 10pt;"><input style="border: none; background-color: transparent; width: 100%;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row->name; ?>:" readonly/></td>
                    <td style=" height: 50px; width: 200px;"><textarea style="resize: none; font-size: 10pt; width: 100%;"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn_add_all_inventory btn-success btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn_cancel_all_inventory btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn_clear_all_inventory btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="document.getElementById('frm_add_all_inventory').reset();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>&nbsp;Clear</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
        </form>
</fieldset>
```

You see my textarea tag is inside the foreach loop, I wonder how can I generate an ID on my textarea on this one. Hope you could help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can do count like $count=0; foreach($add_all_1 as $row) { $generatedId="GENID".$count;/*something instead of GENID*/ $count=$count+1;

Comment: @punithasubramaniv I didn't quite get it, can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: posted, can you check/try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try it?

Is this you are trying for?

```
<?php
    $count=0; /* Initialize variable */
    foreach($add_all_1 as $row) {
?>
      <tr style="">
       <td style=" height: 50px; width: 100px;font-size: 10pt;"><input style="border: none; background-color: transparent; width: 100%;" type="text" value="<?php echo $row->name; ?>:" readonly/></td>
        <td style=" height: 50px; width: 200px;"><textarea style="resize: none; font-size: 10pt; width: 100%;"></textarea></td>
       </tr>
<?php 
     echo 'Generated Id: ID'.$count; /*Something Prefix*/
     $count=$count+1; /*Increase the Variable*/
    } 
?>
```